# Default button in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set the default button in a bootstrap modal. Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/1aLlDdL8WfkUrBVt4q31?p=preview

In the modal window, I want the Submit button to be the default.

[image]

I tried to follow code but did not work.

```
$("#userNameModal").keyup(function(event){
       if(event.keyCode == 13){
           $("#submitUserNameBtn").click();
       }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is it are you trying to do exactly? On key press similar a click on the submit button?

Comment: When the modal dialog is in focus and user clicks on enter key, the 'Submit' button click event should be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Angular i would just use a directive.  That way you can use it across your app (also at the bottom is the link for the working plnkr):

```
.directive('enterSubmit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    if (!event.shiftKey) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        scope.$apply(attrs.enterSubmit);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then call it from you input:

```
enter-submit="submitUserName()"
```

**HERE IS THE WORKING REVISED PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/STXwWPxWIWpDSkIo9ruG?p=preview**

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the code with `<form>` and set correct button types: `type="submit"` for Submit button and `type="button"` for other ones.

The modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XD2UzlBnPbBafWmWfTg0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are so close!  What can do is set focus to the text input, and then listen for the enter keypress on that element.

```
function renameSys() {
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Rename Instrument',
        message: 'Enter new name: <input id="newname" type="text" maxlength=30 class="form-control">',
        buttons: [{
            label: 'OK',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary col-2',
            action: function (dialogRef) {
                return _renameSys(dialogRef);
            },
        }, {            
            label: 'Cancel',
            cssClass: 'btn-secondary col-2',
            action: function (dialogRef) {
                dialogRef.close();
            }
        }],
        onshown: function (dialogRef) {
            $('#newname').focus();
            $("#newname").keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    _renameSys(dialogRef);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The function _renameSys can validate the input data and return false if validation fails, keeping the dialog displayed.

```
function _renameSys(dialogRef) {
    var newname = dialogRef.getModalBody().find('input').val();
    ... // do something
    return true;
}
```